# Form size does not change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window, which shows always smaller than in the designer. No matter how big it is in the designer and how big numbers I put in size in the properties, it always shows small. I tried to put maximum and minimum size, tried with autosize, autovalidate, autoscale options. Despite that, it was always small and the same size. I solved it by putting `form.width` and `form.height` during initialization. But I wonder what happened and how to prevent it in the future. It happened second time for me, and I do not know why. Any tips what to check more?

c# designer

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.newToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 187);
            this.button1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 55);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Segment";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 309);
            this.button2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 55);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Triangle";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 433);
            this.button3.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 55);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button3.Text = "Quadrangle";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this.button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 559);
            this.button4.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.button4.Name = "button4";
            this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 55);
            this.button4.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button4.Text = "Hexagon";
            this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 1027);
            this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(176, 119);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 193);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 0, 8, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 32);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 315);
            this.label2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 0, 8, 0);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 32);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 439);
            this.label3.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 0, 8, 0);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 32);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 565);
            this.label4.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 0, 8, 0);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 32);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 49);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 10;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // fileToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.newToolStripMenuItem,
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem});
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 45);
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
            // 
            // newToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.newToolStripMenuItem.Name = "newToolStripMenuItem";
            this.newToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 46);
            this.newToolStripMenuItem.Text = "New";
            this.newToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.newToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // saveToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Name = "saveToolStripMenuItem";
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 46);
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Save";
            this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.saveToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // splitContainer1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 49);
            this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label7);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.button4);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel2
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 1402);
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 621;
            this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this.label7.AutoSize = true;
            this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(95, 927);
            this.label7.Name = "label7";
            this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(309, 32);
            this.label7.TabIndex = 10;
            this.label7.Text = "A color for new shapes:";
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 98);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 32);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 9;
            this.label6.Text = "Shapes:";
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pictureBox2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1794, 1402);
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 9;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox2.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox2_MouseDoubleClick);
            this.pictureBox2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox2_MouseDown);
            this.pictureBox2.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox2_MouseMove);
            this.pictureBox2.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox2_MouseUp);
            this.pictureBox2.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox2_Resize);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(16F, 31F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnablePreventFocusChange;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 1451);
            this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 7, 8, 7);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Simple Paint";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
            this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem newToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem saveToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
    }
}
```

Form.cs deleted one function because i reached the limit.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool isStrip = false;
        private string NameString;
        private string StorePath;
        private int VertexCatch = -1;
        private int button = -1;
        private int checker = 0;
        private int dblclck = -1;
        private Bitmap graphic;
        private Graphics g;
        private Name NameForm;
        private Point[] points;
        private Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
        private ColorDialog colorDialog1 = new ColorDialog();
        private List<Label> LabelList = new List<Label>();
        private List<Button> ButtonList = new List<Button>();
        private List<Point[]> PointsList = new List<Point[]>();
        private List<Brush> BrushList = new List<Brush>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            graphic = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(graphic);
            LabelList.Add(label1);
            LabelList.Add(label2);
            LabelList.Add(label3);
            LabelList.Add(label4);
            ButtonList.Add(button1);
            ButtonList.Add(button2);
            ButtonList.Add(button3);
            ButtonList.Add(button4);
            this.Width = 1200;
            this.Height = 600;
        }
        private void DrawFullList()
        {
            graphic = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height + 100);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(graphic);
            pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
            for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Count; i++)
            {
                bool yellowframe = false;
                if (i == dblclck)
                    yellowframe = true;
                Draw(BrushList[i], PointsList[i], yellowframe);
            }
        }
        private void Draw(Brush brush, Point[] points, bool yellowframe)
        {
            Pen PathPen = new Pen(brush);
            if (yellowframe)
                PathPen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
            PathPen.Width = 3;
            g.DrawPolygon(PathPen, points);
            g.FillPolygon(brush, points);
            pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
        }

        private int showNumberForButton(int button)
        {
            if (button == -1)
                return 0;
           else if (button > 2)
                return 6;
            else
                return button + 2;
        }
        private void ButtonClick(int buttonint)
        {
            button = buttonint;
            LabelList[button].Text = "Choose " + (showNumberForButton(button)) + " more points\nto construct shape"; ;
            if(showNumberForButton(button) == 2)
                points = new Point[4];
            else
                points = new Point[showNumberForButton(button)];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                ButtonList[i].Enabled = false;
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                p.Color = colorDialog1.Color;
                pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClick(0);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClick(1);
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClick(2);
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClick(3);
        }
        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StorePath = dialog.SelectedPath;
                NameForm = new Name();
                NameForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed);
                NameForm.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You canceled the saving prodedure.\nThe image is not saved.", "Image saving canceled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        private void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            NameString = NameForm.PassName();
            if (NameString != null && StorePath != null)
                graphic.Save(StorePath + "\\" + NameString + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You canceled the saving prodedure.\nThe image is not saved.", "Image saving canceled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (IsPointInPolygon4(PointsList[i], pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
                {
                    dblclck = -1;
                    DrawFullList();
                }
            }
            if (checker < showNumberForButton(button))
            {
                points[checker++] = pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                if (showNumberForButton(button) == 2 && checker == 2)
                {
                    points[2] = new Point(points[1].X + 3, points[1].Y + 3);
                    points[3] = new Point(points[0].X + 3, points[0].Y + 3);
                }
                if (checker == showNumberForButton(button))
                {
                    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(colorDialog1.Color);
                    Draw(brush, points, false);
                    PointsList.Add(points);
                    BrushList.Add(brush);
                    checker = 0;
                    button = -1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        ButtonList[i].Enabled = true;
                        LabelList[i].Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                else
                    LabelList[button].Text = "Choose " + (showNumberForButton(button) - checker) + " more points\nto construct shape";
            }
            Point MouseCatch = pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (IsPointInPolygon4(PointsList[i], MouseCatch))
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < PointsList[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (MouseCatch.X >= PointsList[i][j].X - 20 && MouseCatch.X <= PointsList[i][j].X + 20 && MouseCatch.Y >= PointsList[i][j].Y - 20 && MouseCatch.Y <= PointsList[i][j].Y + 20)
                        {
                            VertexCatch = j;
                            Point[] temp = PointsList[i];
                            Brush tempB = BrushList[i];
                            PointsList.Remove(PointsList[i]);
                            BrushList.Remove(BrushList[i]);
                            PointsList.Add(temp);
                            BrushList.Add(tempB);
                            if (isItStrip(PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1]))
                                isStrip = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            graphic = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
            PointsList.Clear();
            BrushList.Clear();
            checker = 0;
            button = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                ButtonList[i].Enabled = true;
                LabelList[i].Text = string.Empty;
            }
            VertexCatch = -1;
            g = Graphics.FromImage(graphic);
            pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
        }
        private bool isItStrip(Point[] Points)
        {
            if (Points.Length == 4 && (points[2].X == (points[1].X + 3)) && (points[2].Y == points[1].Y + 3) && (points[3].X == (points[0].X + 3)) && (points[0].Y + 3 == points[3].Y))
                return true;
            return false;
       }
        private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (VertexCatch > -1)
            {
                Point k = pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1][VertexCatch] = k;
                if (isStrip)
                {
                    if (VertexCatch == 0)
                        PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1][VertexCatch + 3] = new Point (k.X + 3,k.Y + 3);
                    else if(VertexCatch == 1)
                        PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1][VertexCatch + 1] = new Point(k.X + 3, k.Y + 3);
                    else if (VertexCatch == 2)
                        PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1][VertexCatch - 1] = new Point(k.X - 3, k.Y + 3);
                    else if (VertexCatch == 3)
                        PointsList[PointsList.Count - 1][VertexCatch - 3] = new Point(k.X - 3, k.Y + 3);
                }
                DrawFullList();
            }
        }
        private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isStrip = false;
            VertexCatch = -1;
        }
        private void pictureBox2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                Point MouseCatch = pictureBox2.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                for (int i = PointsList.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--)
                {
                    if (IsPointInPolygon4(PointsList[i], MouseCatch))
                    {
                            dblclck = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                DrawFullList();
        }
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (dblclck != -1) {
                switch (keyData) {
                    case Keys.Left:
                            for (int i = 0; i < PointsList[dblclck].Length; i++)
                                PointsList[dblclck][i].X -= 20;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Right:
                        for (int i = 0; i < PointsList[dblclck].Length; i++)
                            PointsList[dblclck][i].X += 20;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Up:
                        for (int i = 0; i < PointsList[dblclck].Length; i++)
                            PointsList[dblclck][i].Y -= 20;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Down:
                        for (int i = 0; i < PointsList[dblclck].Length; i++)
                            PointsList[dblclck][i].Y += 20;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Enter:
                        dblclck = -1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
                }
                DrawFullList();
                return true;
        }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        private void pictureBox2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawFullList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid artificially adding tags to your question titles.  See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Post `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` please (where `Form1` is your form name).

Answer (score 0):

The form in the designer is set 2419 x 1451 pixels... if this is larger than the screen WinForms ignores the setting of that property (check `this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2419, 1451);` in your `Form1.designer.cs` file), so the window gets a "default" size.

Set your form to a reasonable size within the designer (1200 x 600, for example, like you are doing on your constructor).

If you are setting it to 1200x600 but still is getting serialized as 2419x1451, then you may have hit one of the **MANY** problems the winform designer has with high-dpi displays. Set your `AutoscaleMode` to `None` and it should not try to adjust the properties to the "current" dpi upon serializing.

Comment: It's not about the designer pixels value. It's probably the problem with high dpi. I have 4k resolution on 15.6 inch display. Actually I tried with Autoscale settings as i WROTE in the topic

Comment: Yes, but after setting autoscale to none, did you check the form's stored width and height?

Comment: Yea, it somehow works, but, it show me much bigger controls than in design form. If I want them to be displayed in "normal" size, I must project the form in barely visible size

Comment: @Vinci yes... I wished there was any valid workaround, but the winforms designer is just deeply flawed at high-dpi... all workarounds I've tried fail in one way or another. I've ended up doing WPF (which I dislike a lot) for desktop dpi-aware apps

Comment: Okey, Thank you very much, I'll stary with forcing it by width and height :)